# Реклама в мобильных приложениях

Tags: ios, apple, мобильная-разработка, реклама

Знающие люди, подскажите пожалуйста.
Можно ли в мобильное приложение  ios, встраивать стороннюю рекламу?

То есть, допустим написал приложение, и в определенное место подгружаю рекламный блок, будь то контекст, тизер или баннер?
Не ли у apple ограничений?

И то же самое хотелось бы узнать про android.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, Вы можете использовать сторонню рекламу, кроме Apple iAd.
Например, admob от гугла https://www.google.com/admob/.

i-vango:  http://i-vengo.com/

или другие, если они не нарушают правила Apple о расположении баннеров и о показе запрещенного контента.

Вы так же можете посмотреть некоторые правила о рекламе у Apple 
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#advertising

> Apps that artificially increase the number of impressions or
>   click-throughs of ads will be rejected
>
> Apps that contain empty iAd banners will be rejected
>
> Apps that are designed predominantly for the display of ads will be
>   rejected

Аналогично и для Android.
Правила в отношении рекламы (Google Play) - https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ru/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: @Сергей всегда пожалуйста! Удачи Вам! И не забудьте отметить ответ правильным ;)